# how does optional argument `ALLOW-EXTEND` in `mark-word` work?

Tags: commands, prefix-argument

I am switching from VIM to Emacs for just a couple weeks and trying to write some Elisp. Having difficulties to adapt, I am exploring different options to do marking and reached this function.

```
(defun mark-word (&optional arg allow-extend)                          
  "Set mark ARG words away from point.                                 
The place mark goes is the same place \\[forward-word] would           
move to with the same argument.                                        
Interactively, if this command is repeated                             
or (in Transient Mark mode) if the mark is active,                     
it marks the next ARG words after the ones already marked."            
  (interactive "P\np")                                                 
  (cond ((and allow-extend                                             
              (or (and (eq last-command this-command) (mark t))        
                  (region-active-p)))                                  
         (setq arg (if arg (prefix-numeric-value arg)                  
                     (if (< (mark) (point)) -1 1)))                    
         (set-mark                                                     
          (save-excursion                                              
            (goto-char (mark))                                         
            (forward-word arg)                                         
            (point))))                                                 
        (t                                                             
         (push-mark                                                    
          (save-excursion                                              
            (forward-word (prefix-numeric-value arg))                  
            (point))                                                   
          nil t))))
```

it's pretty straight forward except `allow-extend`. It seems to me for this function to work, `allow-extend` needs to be empty. But when we do interaction, we don't really provide any prefix key to it.

So why would `allow-extend` be non `nil` in this case? Also how does `"P\np"` work here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @db48x pointed out, indeed `C-u` passes in 2 arguments down to the function if it's pressed, but it wouldn't be the case if it's not pressed in the first place.

The trick here is the second argument is `p`, lower case. That converts the second argument to a number when called by `call-interactively` regardless, which has no chance to be `nil`.

Examination,

```
M-: (defun try-it (&optional a b) (interactive "P\np") (message "a is %s and b is %s" a b))
```

then

```
M-x try-it
```

gives

```
a is nil and b is 1
```

while

```
C-u M-x try-it
```

gives

```
a is (4) and b is 4
```

Answer (score 1):

The interactive declaration specifies that the function wants two arguments. The code letters for the arguments are `P` and `p`. If we examine the help for `interactive` (by typing `C-h f interactive <RET>`), we can see what these mean:

```
p -- Prefix arg converted to number.  Does not do I/O.
P -- Prefix arg in raw form.  Does not do I/O.
```

This means that the single prefix arg is passed to `mark-word` twice; first in raw form (it's a list of numbers, as I recall), then in the form of an integer.

Edit: of course, a non-interactive caller can provide any args they want, so while this command always gets a number (which is always a true value) when called interactively, there might be non-interactive callers that pass in nil to turn off that behavior. I did not consider, when I wrote this answer, that this might be not be obvious.

Comment: This is in fact not a complete answer, I  will answer this myself.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr: What do you think is missing from this answer? It does mention that `p` converts the prefix argument to a number. The only thing I see in your answer that's not here are some (unnecessary, I'd say) examples.

Comment: I'm sorry but after reading you answer, I'm still confused about why the second argument is not nil, thinking it should be as nobody pass it. My question is about why the second argument is not nil, I don't see you answered that.

Comment: When Emacs calls an interactive function, it first builds an argument list. It uses the code letters from the `interactive` declaration to decide what arguments to pass. This function asks for two arguments, and both of them come from the prefix arg. Thus the single prefix argument that the user created with `C-u` becomes two arguments that are passed to this function.

Comment: you haven't got it yet. I understand what happens when `C-u` is pressed. my question is about why the second argument isn't `nil` even if `C-u` is not pressed. as I said, you didn't really explain this part as it's stated in my original question as the most confusing part.

Comment: `But when we do interaction, we don't really provide any prefix key to it.

So why would allow-extend be non nil in this case?` all you said was correct, except that it indeed didn't answer the question completely.

Comment: Because it calls `prefix-numeric-value` on it, and the numeric value of the prefix argument is always 1 if the prefix argument is nil. Why is this, you ask? Well, most commands that use the numeric form of the prefix argument do so because they want the user to be able to repeat the command. That is `C-u 42 M-x foo` should tell `foo` to do it's thing 42 times. If the user doesn't give a prefix argument, then `foo` should do it's thing one time. If a `nil` prefix argument got converted to a zero, then `foo` would do nothing, and the user would be sad.

Comment: Now, because this function never receives a nil value for `allow-extend`, you might think that it can't be functioning properly. Fortunately it's saved by the other check in that cond clause. It only takes that first option if both `allow-extend` is true and the last command that the user executed was `mark-word`. This is equivalent to just checking the last command, and ignoring `allow-extend`. But there's one other scenario: the command might have been called non-interactively. A non-interactive caller doesn't have to give the "right" arguments, and so they can pass in nil if they want too.